# Cocoapods install pod with subspec did not work

Tags: objective-c, ruby-on-rails, xcode, dependency-management, cocoapods

Hello i am creating podspecs for my private lib that works great but when i create a podspec with subspecs validate with $ pod spec lint [podname].podspec will be successfull

But when i will add this pod and say $ pod install

I get allways this error:

#### Error

```
ArgumentError - Malformed version number string Loader
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-0.32.1/lib/cocoapods-core/vendor/version.rb:191:in `initialize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-0.32.1/lib/cocoapods-core/version.rb:60:in `initialize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-0.32.1/lib/cocoapods-core/source/file_system_data_provider.rb:61:in `new'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-0.32.1/lib/cocoapods-core/source/file_system_data_provider.rb:61:in `block in versions'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-0.32.1/lib/cocoapods-core/source/file_system_data_provider.rb:59:in `map'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-0.32.1/lib/cocoapods-core/source/file_system_data_provider.rb:59:in `versions'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-0.32.1/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:90:in `versions'
```

My podspec looks like thist:

sp.dependency 'Globals','~> 0.0.1' and sp.dependency 'Extensions','~> 0.0.1' was private pods and they will work fine.

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = "Networking"
  s.version      = "0.0.2"
  s.summary      = "Networking for Handling Network"

  s.description  = "Networking handling Network and blabla"
  s.homepage     = "http://www.myhp.at"

  # ―――  Spec License  ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― #

  s.license = { :type => 'MIT', :text => <<-LICENSE
                   Copyright 2014 blabla
                 LICENSE
               }

  # ――― Author Metadata  ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― #

  s.author             = { "MyName" => "me@me.at" }

  # ――― Platform Specifics ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― #

  s.platform     = :ios, "5.0"

  # ――― Source Location ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― #

  s.source       = { :git => "https://myurl/myrepo.git", :tag => "0.0.2" }

  # ――― Source Code ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― #

  # s.source_files  = "Networking/"
  # s.exclude_files = "Classes/Exclude"
  # s.public_header_files = "Classes/**/*.h"

  s.subspec 'Loader' do |sp|
        sp.source_files = 'Networking/Loader' 
        sp.dependency 'ASIHTTPRequest', '~> 1.8'
        sp.dependency 'Globals','~> 0.0.1'
        sp.dependency 'Extensions','~> 0.0.1'
  end

  s.subspec 'L1DataFeed' do |sp|
        sp.source_files = 'Networking/DataFeed'     
        sp.frameworks   = 'CoreData'
        sp.dependency 'ASIHTTPRequest', '~> 1.8'
        sp.dependency 'Globals','~> 0.0.1'
        sp.dependency 'Extensions','~> 0.0.1'
  end

  s.subspec 'L1NetworkManager' do |sp|
        sp.source_files = 'Networking/NetworkManager'       
        sp.dependency 'Networking/DataFeed'
        sp.dependency 'ASIHTTPRequest', '~> 1.8'
        sp.dependency 'Globals','~> 0.0.1'
        sp.dependency 'Extensions','~> 0.0.1' 
  end

  # ――― Resources ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― #

  # s.resource  = "icon.png"
  # s.resources = "Resources/*.png"

  # s.preserve_paths = "FilesToSave", "MoreFilesToSave"

  # ――― Project Linking ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― #

  # s.framework  = "SomeFramework"
  # s.frameworks = "SomeFramework", "AnotherFramework"

  # s.library   = "iconv"
  # s.libraries = "iconv", "xml2"

  # ――― Project Settings ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― #

  s.requires_arc = true

  # s.xcconfig = { "HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS" => "$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2" }
  #s.dependency 'ASIHTTPRequest', '~> 1.8', '>= 1.8.2'
  #s.dependency 'Globals','~> 0.0.1'
  #s.dependency 'Extensions','~> 0.0.1'

end
```

the Folder Structure looks like so:

root:

- Networking
- --> Loader
- --> DataFeed
- --> NetworkManager

so can someone help me with this problem?

I tryed to make an other podspec with subspecs same problem.

Comment: Can you post the folder structure you're using in your podspec is in?

Comment: Hi the folder structure looks so
../Networking/Loader and
../Networking/DataFeed and 
../Networking/NetworkManager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception backtrace seems to indicate that this happens when reading in specs from disk. Could it be that you have a `Loader` directory in a spec dir that normally should contain a version dir?

E.g. this **only** contains version dirs:

`$ ls -l ~/.cocoapods/repos/master/AFNetworking/
drwxr-xr-x  3 eloy  staff  102 Feb  2 14:14 2.0.0
drwxr-xr-x  3 eloy  staff  102 Feb  2 14:14 2.0.0-RC1
drwxr-xr-x  3 eloy  staff  102 Feb  2 14:14 2.0.0-RC2
drwxr-xr-x  3 eloy  staff  102 Feb  2 14:14 2.0.0-RC3
drwxr-xr-x  3 eloy  staff  102 Feb  2 14:14 2.0.1
drwxr-xr-x  3 eloy  staff  102 Feb  2 14:14 2.0.2
drwxr-xr-x  3 eloy  staff  102 Feb  2 14:14 2.0.3
drwxr-xr-x  3 eloy  staff  102 Feb  2 14:14 2.1.0
drwxr-xr-x  3 eloy  staff  102 Mar  3 17:42 2.2.0
drwxr-xr-x  3 eloy  staff  102 Mar 15 13:05 2.2.1
drwxr-xr-x  3 eloy  staff  102 Apr 16 13:33 2.2.2`

Comment: Yes i have in the Networking folder Sub folders Loader, DataFeed and NetworkManager.
is that not good?
must i create an own spec for the Loader?

Comment: No no, I am asking you about there being a Loader did in the versions dir of your podspec repo, **not** your code repo. Can you expand your question to show exactly how you are including the podspec in your Podfile?

Comment: i have add this podspec to my private repo with $ pod repo add lib Networking.podspec. and then i include it in my pod file with pod 'L1Networking','~> 0.0.2'

Comment: so when i remove all subfolder in the Networking folder it will work fine. Is there any soulution for handling this with subfolders? like ASIHTTPRequest.podspec https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/tree/master/Classes  there was subfolders S3, ...

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do that as you show in your podspec. Again, I suspect it is an incorrect version dir called ‘Loader’ in your private spec repo. Please verify that or show the output of `tree ~/.cocoapods/repos/your-private-repo` (you can install `tree` through Homebrew).

Comment: In the dir ~/.cocoapods/repos/lib/Networking  was the subfolders 0.0.2, Loader, DataFeed and Networking in this folders are also my source flies from the lib Reop

Comment: That’s the problem, a spec repo should only contain pod specs, as I showed above with the AFNetworking example. It should **not** contain your lib repo. See the guide on private spec repos for more info: http://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html.